# Error when execute query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, webforms

HI here is code snippet of C#. I am trying to generate a summary of data and display in formview in asp.net. But having a issue with this code generating error that 
`'Incorrect syntax near 'K12'.'`
please help me out.

```
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=ARSLAN-   LAPI\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                              "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                              "database=OTTS; " +
                              "connection timeout=30");
                String query = "Select * FROM dbo.";
                query = query + " " + "[" + session.SelectedItem.Text + "_" +     dept.SelectedItem.Text + "]";
                query = query + " " + "WHERE rollNo=" + "2K12-BSCS-37";
                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                //SqlDataReader reader;
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                dataform.DataSource = table;
                dataform.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text="Error ::"+ ex.Message;
            }
```

Comment: Veryt dangerous code. I hope for you that these dropdowns are not writeable from your user

Comment: A few issues with your question: 1) The title is unclear. "Confused with below code of C#" is not something anyone will ever actually search for on the internet. A closer problem title would be, "incorrect syntax error in C# when (... *What you're trying to do*...)"  2) We don't have your Database schema for what you're looking at, so we don't know what the syntax should be necessarily.

Comment: @Steve They most likely are if they are usable in a form, since an end user could just craft an HTTP request with a form that has whatever they want as form data.  The OP would have to have some sort of validation to ensure the values are within a range they expect.

Comment: if i remove space than also Same problem

Comment: @George:::Sir i am trying to put some data to formview from database database name is '2K12_BSCS' which is enclosed in square brackets. when i selected 2K12 and BSCS from cascade dropdownlist and then new dropdownlist generated of roll numbers. after selection of roll no i want to add all data of certain roll number to form. i am new to asp.net and c#.

Comment: i started asp.net and c# 5 days ago .
i don't know about it so please help me where i am making mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The roll number string in your where clause needs to be delimited as a string. This line `query = query + " " + "WHERE rollNo=" + "2K12-BSCS-37";` should be replaced with `query += " " + "WHERE rollNo=" + "'2K12-BSCS-37'";` Note the single quotes.

Better still would be to use string format to build your query, something like this:

```
string.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.[{0}_{1}] WHERE rollNo = '{2}'",
              session.SelectedItem.Text,
              dept.SelectedItem.Text,
              "2K12-BSCS-37")
```

And even better *still* would be to avoid this dangerous query altogether, since it exposes your database to numerous possible attacks. I have honestly never let users build their own table name in this fashion, so I can't even say if the SQLClient parameters would work here, though I expect they will not. I agree with previous comments that much range checking, etc. will be required to make this viable.

In the end, hopefully this is an internal application that only a select few users will ever have access to.

Comment: Thankx sir now error is removed can you just guide me how can i add data to formview control of asp.net

Comment: Ehm, shorter:
query += " WHERE rollNo='2K12-BSCS-37'";
By the way, StringBuilder is better suited for that purpose.
And, of course, a "parameterized query" is required here instead of concatenating the value into the query directly.
(I did not downvote.)